# How to addclass to current active div in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have few similar blocks with similar content. If I hover on **first block**, for **first block** and one other **sub-block** in this **first parent block** classes should be added. And for the second block too: if I hover on **second block** for **second block** and **sub-block** in **this parent second block** shold be added the same classes.

Actually I can do unique classes or indentify for each block seperatly but I this this isn't correct and if I want to add I more block I have to change css, html and javascript code - this is uncomfortable.

```js
var Block1 = $('.point-to-black');

ShopBlock1.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('c-lb-black');
    $('.c-lb-text-zone').addClass('c-lb-tz-full');
});
ShopBlock1.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('c-lb-black');
    $('.c-lb-text-zone').removeClass('c-lb-tz-full');
});
```

```css
.point-to-black {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.c-lb-black{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)!important;
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 100px!important;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.c-lb-tz-full {
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 33%!important;
    padding: 3px 25%!important;
    font-size: 25px!important;
    transform: skew(-20deg)!important;
    background: #c1af25!important;
    line-height: 33px!important;
}
.c-lb-text-zone1 {
 line-height: 33px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 transition: 0.3s;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 50%;
 padding: 3px 15%;
 font-size: 25px;
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background: #c1af25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="c-link-list">
    <li>
        <div class="c-lb-blog">
            <div class="point-to-black">
                <div class="c-lb-text-zone">
                    <h1>Blog1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="c-lb-blog">
            <div class="point-to-black">
                <div class="c-lb-text-zone">
                    <h1>Blog2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So if I do mouseover on **`'point-to-black'`** block **`'c-lb-black'`** class adds good just for current block because of **`'this'`** pointer but **`'c-lb-tz-full'`** adds for all blocks with class**`'c-lb-text-zone'`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).find('.c-lb-text-zone').addClass('c-lb-tz-full');
```

And

```
$(this).find('.c-lb-text-zone').removeClass('c-lb-tz-full');
```

It will affect only the children of the specific div.